# Confused by the compareTo answer

Tags: java, inheritance, compareto

//The answer is 2 not sure why. Does it not invoke the object/class instance
//method if the method is overridden. Basically why is it invoking compareTo in the Person class instead of SoccerPlayer, why is the answer 2???? Thanks in advance

```
public class Person implements Comparable {
    private String name;

    public Person(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return other != null && name.equals(((Person) other).name);
    }

    public int compareTo(Object other) {
        return name.compareTo((Person other).name);
    }

    public int hashCode() { return name.hashCode(); }
}

public class SoccerPlayer extends Person {
    private int numGoals;

    public SoccerPlayer(String name, int n) {
        super(name);
        numGoals = n;
    }

    public int getNumGoals() { return numGoals; }
    public void score() [ numGoals++; }

    public int compareTo(SoccerPlayer other) {
        return getNumGoals() - other.getNumGoals();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getName() + "/" + getNumGoals();
    }
}
```

What is the result of the following code? //why 2???

```
Person players[] = { new SoccerPlayer("Mia Hamm", 7), new SoccerPlayer("Kristine Lilly", 6) };
System.out.println(players[0].compareTo((SoccerPlayer) players[1]));     // Line ***
```

a. Syntax error in the class Person: other.name is not accessible

b. Syntax error in the class SoccerPlayer: compareTo is redefined

c.  ClassCaseException on Line ***

d. Compiles with no errors, displays 1

e. Compiles with no errors, displays 2

Comment: Both these answers are wrong as they use raw types.

Answer (score 3):

There is no overriding here. One `compareTo` method takes an `Object` as argument, and the other takes a `SoccerPlayer`.

That's overloading, not overriding. Two methods with the same name, but not the same signature.

Since the declared type of the variable `players[0]` is Person, all the compiler knowns about this variable is that it's a Person, with a single `compareTo` method taking an Object as argument. So that method is the one being called.

Note that this code would have been fine a bit more than 10 years ago, when we were using Java 4, and generics didn't exist. Nowadays, using raw types is really bad practice. Person should implement `Comparable<Person>`, not `Comparable`.

Also note that the equals() implementation is wrong, too. It should return false rather than throw a ClassCastException if the object passed as argument is not a Person.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply I understand !